# Truffle stuck when deploy smart contract when using Ledger wallet

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment, ledger-nano-s

I have a little problem deploying smart contract with ledger nano s as provider on ropsten. The script just remain stuck at first migration

```
Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'ropsten'
> Network id:      3
> Block gas limit: 8000029 (0x7a121d)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x1b85c85699b9f40798b5892a7492c303048915e80ac69803f94e617744769865
   ⠋ Blocks: 211          Seconds: 2829
```

This is my truffle configuration

```
require("dotenv").config();
const gasPrice = require("./get_gas_price");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();

const LedgerProviderRopsten = require('./ledger-provider-ropsten');
const LedgerProviderMainnet = require('./ledger-provider-mainnet');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.BLOCKCHAIN_NODE_ROPSTEN),
      network_id: "*",
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: () => LedgerProviderMainnet,
      network_id: 1,
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei((gasPrice.fast / 10).toString(), "gwei"),
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => LedgerProviderRopsten,
      network_id: 3,
      gasPrice: 20000000000
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.6.9",
      settings: {
        optimizer: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

### Ledger provider configuration

```
const LedgerWalletProvider = require('@ledgerhq/web3-subprovider');
const createLedgerSubprovider = LedgerWalletProvider.default;
const TransportNodeHid = require('@ledgerhq/hw-transport-node-hid').default;
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine');
const RpcSubprovider = require('web3-provider-engine/subproviders/rpc');
// const logger = require("@ledgerhq/logs");
// logger.listen(log => console.log(log));

const localNode = 'http://127.0.0.1:8545';

const getTransport = () => TransportNodeHid.create();
const ledger = createLedgerSubprovider(getTransport, {
    networkId: 3, paths: ["44'/1'/0'/0/0"], askConfirm: false,
});

const engine = new ProviderEngine();
engine.addProvider(ledger);
// process.env.BLOCKCHAIN_NODE_ROPSTEN 
engine.addProvider(new RpcSubprovider({ rpcUrl: process.env.BLOCKCHAIN_NODE_ROPSTEN }));
engine.start();

module.exports = engine;
```

---

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20
Ethereum client: geth Version: 1.9.15-stable
Truffle version (truffle version): 5.1.29
node version (node --version): 10.21.0
npm version (npm --version): 6.14.5
```

Comment: You should specify `gasPrice` in your Truffle configuration file.

Comment: @goodvibration if I do that, I get different error. "Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests"

Comment: Am I supposed to guess how you do that? Please share your entire truffle configuration.

Comment: @goodvibration I edit the post and add the full configuration. I see that adding gas price to low will throw the error "Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests" but adding a correct gas price will not change anything

Comment: @goodvibration I have another configuration in truffle, testnet that work. But the problem is when I want to deploy the contract and sign with ledger nano s

Comment: I would suggest you write your contract in a way that you deploy the contract from a private key stored in a configuration file, then move the ownership to Ledger account. See here for examples https://github.com/Dawn-Protocol/dawn-erc20-erc777 - Ledger tends to be very problematic device with web3.js.